# Get Dummies for Column with Multiple Variables

Tags: python, pandas

So I am working with a dataframe and it has a column where it essentially lists all the genres that apply to a movie, like this:

```
                                             Genres
0       Action, Adventure, Fantasy, Science Fiction
1                        Adventure, Fantasy, Action
2                          Action, Adventure, Crime
3                    Action, Crime, Drama, Thriller
4                Action, Adventure, Science Fiction
                           ...                     
4798                        Action, Crime, Thriller
4799                                Comedy, Romance
4800               Comedy, Drama, Romance, TV Movie
4801                                               
4802                                    Documentary
```

Basically I want to create dummies for the genres but I am having difficulty doing it when several categorical variables apply, is there any way I can do this?
Thanks!

Comment: `df.Genres.str.get_dummies(', ')`?

Comment: thank you! this fixed it